# How to delete the upstream project reference in a GitLab project?

Tags: gitlab, project, git-fork, upstream

I forked a GitLab project, and now on the main page there is a panel with this message: "forked from [...] 1 commit ahead of the upstream repository" and a big "Create merge request" button. But I just don't need this upstream repo anymore, so I want to delete any reference to it in the current project. How to do this?

All I was able to find is: `Settings` -> `Merge requests` -> `Target project` where I can specify "the default target project for merge requests created in this fork project". However the upstream project is still there, which I don't want.

This is GitLab Web UI as supplied by [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com).

Thanks!